# regarding streams in c++

Tags: c++, ostream

I want to use file streams and consol output stream. In constructor, I want to initialize with either file or consol output stream depending on parameter passed to constructor. Then I will have another function in class which will redirect output to that stream. what will be the code for it? I am trying with the below code which is not working. 
Any other design suggestions are welcome.

```
class Test
{
    private:

        std::ios *obj;
        std::ofstream file;
        std::ostream cout1;
    public:
//      Test(){}
        Test(char choice[])
        {
            if(choice=="file")
            {
                obj=new ofstream();
                obj->open("temp.txt");
            }
            else
                obj=new ostream();


        }
        void printarray()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<5;i++)

                     (*obj)<<"\n \n"<<"HI"
        }
};
```

Comment: Why not just a single `std::ostream &` member where you pass in a stream?

Comment: This sounds like asking about your invented solution Y to real problem X. What is the real problem X?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I am trying to solve the problem which I have explained by the code I have mentioned which is not working.

Comment: @chris could you please provide code what you are saying.

Comment: @debonair what chris meant was have *the caller* pass in either a `std::ofstream` or `std::cout` as a single construction parameter and initialize (and later use) a `std::ostream&` from *that* parameter. The caller owns file stream passed in if that is the route taken, otherwise it just passes in `std::cout`

Comment: @debonair: Please don't change the code like that.  Sure the code was wrong, but your change now hides one misunderstanding the OP has, so that it's now hard for us to realize what he's trying to do and so we can't correct him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
   private:

      std::ofstream file;
      std::ostream& obj;

   public:

      // Use overloaded constructors. When the default constructor is used,
      // use std::cout. When the constructor with string is used, use the argument
      // as the file to write to.
      Test() : obj(std::cout) {}
      Test(std::string const& f) : file(f.c_str()), obj(file) {}

      void printarray()
      {
         for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            obj<<"\n " << "HI" << " \n";
      }
}; 

int main()
{
   Test a;
   a.printarray();

   Test b("out.txt");
   b.printarray();
}
```

**PS** Look at the changes to `printarray`. What you were trying, with `%s`, is good for the `printf` family of functions but not for `std::ostream`.

Answer (score 1):

> Any other design suggestions are welcome.

Two of these members are useless:

```
    std::ios *obj;
    std::ofstream file;
    std::ostream cout1;
```

You can't do anything with a `std::ios`, a `std::ostream` that isn't associated with a `streambuf` is useless, and you never use `file` or `cout1` anyway!

You want:

```
    std::ofstream file;
    std::ostream& out;
```

as shown in R Sahu's answer, and write to `out`.

```
    Test(char choice[])
    {
        if(choice=="file")
```

This doesn't work, you need to use `strcmp` to compare `char` strings. You should probably use `std::string` not `char*`.